# ng-reflect-model shows correct value but not reflecting in input

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

Encountered a very weird issue where my application misbehaves in a very specific user case. I have a portal where users can add questions and answers and then edit them. In this case when I remove a set(q+a) and then try adding it, the model is getting updated but my view takes values from placeholders and updates itself. Here I am just splicing and pushing values in an array and rendering using ngFor. The last element is a dummy and that is used to enter values which are pushed up.

Attaching a screenshot if it makes any sense.

You can see that for the textbox, the ng-reflect-model shows correct question, but the element itself displays the placeholder text.

[image]

Comment: please add some code

Comment: Got it resolved by adding trackBy in ngFor

Comment: please add code that solved your problem so other can get solution. thank you

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently the issue was being caused because Angular wasn't able to track the elements of my array properly. I found this out very hard way. So just adding a trackBy attribute to my ngFor, I was able to resolve this.

Added this to my component:

```
customTrackBy(index: number, obj: any): any {
  return index;
}
```

and then in the template:

```
<div class="margin-bottom-15"
     *ngFor="let assessment of language.assessments; trackBy:customTrackBy">
```

So basically I am asking angular to track my elements in the array by index. It resolved the issue.

Here assessment is the model for each of the question-answer set.

Comment: It is probably one of the most useful posts I've read ever here. I think it is the rare case as you don't need to pay more attention to spelling, because your content compensates it. Although you can :-)

Comment: \o/ Thanks Peter! You made my day.

Comment: Thanks dude for saving my day

Comment: Hours of scratching my head and finally this helped me ;) . Very strange it happened only after Angular upgrade . Can anyone explain why would this happen at all ?

Answer (score 5):

In case if you are using nested ngFor then name attributes might not unique. It should be unique. So suffix **name** attribute with indexes of for loop to make it unique.

```
 <form #f="ngForm" validate>
      <div *ngFor="childItem of parentArray; index as pIndex;">
           <div *ngFor="childArray of childItem.parameters;index as cIndex;">
                 First Name: <input name="childArray-{{pIndex+''+cIndex}}" 
                 type="text" [(ngModel)]="childArray.firstname" required>
                 Last Name: <input name="childArray-{{pIndex+''+cIndex}}" 
                 type="text" [(ngModel)]="childArray.lastname" required>

                <button type="button" [disabled]="!f.valid"
                (click)="submitForm();"> Submit  </button>
            </div>
       </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

else you can use

```
*ngFor="childItem of parentArray; index as i;"
```

and

```
[attr.data-target]="'#test' + i"
```

and

```
name="test{{i}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I checked the inputs and I found duplicated attribute name by mistake (classic wrong copy and paste).

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>LABEL</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder"
           [(ngModel)]="entity.attribute"
            name="attribute_repited"       --------> Duplicated
            #attribute_repited="ngModel">  --------> Doplicated
     </mat-form-field>
     ...
```

Then I change the attribute name, deleting the duplicity, and it works again