# Databinding ngFor* input in table doesn't work as expected

Tags: angular, ngfor

```
 <tr *ngFor="let p of personen; let i=index">
          <td>  <input [(ngModel)]="p.Vorname" name="p.Vorname" type="text" class="form-control" required ></td>
          <td> <input [(ngModel)]="p.Nachname" name="p.Nachname" type="text" class="form-control" required ></td>
          <td> <input [(ngModel)]="p.Geburtsdatum" name="p.Geburtsdatum" type="date" class="form-control" required ></td>
          <button (click)="premove(i)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Entfernen</button>
        </tr>
```

If I add a new item with

```
  this.personen.push(new Person())
```

data in my array 'personen' is OK, but my input fields on my page are shown as empty.

Comment: Any error in the browser consoleß

Comment: no, there is no error.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the `name` property is unique:

```ts
    <tr *ngFor="let p of personen; let i=index">
      <td>  <input [(ngModel)]="p.Vorname" name="Vorname{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" required ></td>
      <td> <input [(ngModel)]="p.Nachname" name="Nachname{{i}}" type="text" class="form-control" required ></td>
      <td> <input [(ngModel)]="p.Geburtsdatum" name="Geburtsdatum{{i}}" type="date" class="form-control" required ></td>
      <button (click)="premove(i)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Entfernen</button>
    </tr>
```

Comment: This doesn't help - the same behavior.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think it's the name property. You can't have multiple inputs with the same name value.

Comment: Further investigation: the objects on page seem to be the "same". I added two classes (ng-valid and ng-invalid) and I see that all items in the same column have the same class. ng-reflect-name is the same. I think this is the problem. "personen[i].Vorname" is static and not computed as "personen[0].Vorname", "personen[1].Vorname" etc.

Comment: ng-reflect-name with string interpolation works, but the effect is the same - the content of the input fields are empty after adding an element.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce in a Plunker? Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 Template

Comment: It shows a strange behavior if you add some items and after that trying to input something.

Comment: Thanks for the Plunker. I'll have a look later. I have to finish urgent work.

Comment: Your code in the Plunker is different than in the question. If `personen` is an array of strings, then you need to use `ngForTrackBy`, but if it is an array of objects the code should work fine. https://plnkr.co/edit/hMOX5aHBokV2IlISe3fs?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. This works indeed. I will examine where the difference between the model in plunker an my real application is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663198/ng-reflect-model-shows-correct-value-but-not-reflecting-in-input   - solved my problem (implementing a trackby method)