# Angular 15 *ngFor not rendering content that is present in array. Cache?

Tags: angular

i just encountered weird behaviour about *ngFor directive, and ran out of possible explanations for this situation.

Here is the code for component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo',
  templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demo.component.less'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DemoComponent {

  public fields: Field[] = [];

  constructor(private changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  public onExternalEvent(): void {
    this.reloadFields();
  }

  private reloadFields(): void {
    this.fields = [{ controlName: 'Name 1' }, { controlName: 'Name 2' }];

    this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

And it's template:

```
<other-component (myEvent)="onExternalEvent()"></other-component>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="gt-t" style="background-color:red;">{{fields | json}}</th>
        <th class="gt-t" style="background-color:blue;" *ngFor="let field of fields">{{field | json}}</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As You can see, when "other-component" emits "myEvent", i trigger reloadFields method, that affects "fields" property that should be rendered in a template.
Additionally i manually notify changeDetectionRef about changes.

After the event was emitted, result looks as follows:
[image]

And in page structure its rendered as:
[image]

The fact, that its rendered by {{fields | json}} prooves that this data is assigned into controller's field. However *ngFor didnt render it.

Even the comment in page structure suggests that there are some objects:
"ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"

But why it's not rendered ?

Fun fact:
If we create one slight modification, adding a fields initial value in controller:

```
public fields: Field[] = [{controlName: 'Initial Item'}];
```

and keep reloadFields method in same shape, result looks as follows:
[image]

How could next two lines in template, both using same collection "fields", render completely different content?

Is it cached somehow ?

What i strive for:
I expect directive *ngFor, to render two tags  individually, with data provided in .
I want to get rid of {{fields | json}}, and display only looped ones (Name 1, Name 2, on blue background).

Thank You!

Comment: Where is the call to this method onExternalEvent()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663198/ng-reflect-model-shows-correct-value-but-not-reflecting-in-input

Comment: @BrendanB adding tracking by index didn't change anytching

Comment: @JoseVicente method "onExternalEvent" is called in the template. Its triggered by "myEvent" sent by "other-component"

Inside "other-component", "myEvent" is defined as follows:
`@Output() private myEvent: EventEmitter<Item | null> = new EventEmitter<Item | null>();`

and its emitted inside ngAfterViewInit, and after click. When i click, it seems to be working fine, but initial emission made inside ngAfterViewInit didnt cause reloading the *ngFor (but reloaded {{fields | json}})

Comment: Additionally, if i added in DemoComponent's template:

`<p (click)="testClick()">click</p>`

And inside Component:

`public testClick(): void {
    console.log('click');
  }`

after click, *ngFor gets refreshed and displays what i want. The data is present inside "fields". It's only reluctant to be rendered

Comment: It's looks like work: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-6w5gyi?file=src%2Fmain.ts), has you import CommonModule? (it's for the *ngFor)

Answer (score 0):

I have found maybe not elegant, but working solution:

```
private reloadFields(): void {
    this.fields = [{ controlName: 'Name 1' }, { controlName: 'Name 2' }];
    
    // It was commented out
    // this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();

    // It was introduced
    setTimeout(() => this.changeDetectionRef.detectChanges());
  }
```

Without any other changes, it caused the expected behaviour. Just after view init, without any clicks, effect looks like on screen.

However, i'll keep on trying to find better way to achieve this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `markForCheck`, not `detectChanges`. This is because the internal state of the component has changed. `detectChanges` will not detect anything.